# I'm having problems exporting my blender file into Unreal, it is saying "Not found assets with "Export recursive" properties or collection to export"

Tags: error, unreal-engine

I'm extremely new at Blender so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm following a tutorial on getting my rigged character into UE5 but I have met an error. I checked for potential errors and I even rebooted my file to see if I was just bugging but I'm met with the same thing.[image]